# Ordenar o maior por pedido

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa noite, estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
select 
   cliente_id, 
   desconto,
   pedidos_detalhes.pedido_id, 
   cliente_tipo 
from 
   pedidos_detalhes
inner join 
   pedidos on pedidos_detalhes.pedido_id = pedidos.pedido_id;
```

O resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço para trazer os 10 clientes que obtiveram os maiores descontos por pedido, sem que o mesmo valor de desconto seja repetido.

desde já agradeço...

Answer (score 0):

Está ai a sua solução amigo.

```
select 
    cliente_id, 
    desconto, 
    pedidos_detalhes.pedido_id, 
    cliente_tipo 
from 
    pedidos_detalhes 
inner join 
    pedidos on pedidos_detalhes.pedido_id = pedidos.pedido_id 
GROUP BY 
    desconto
ORDER BY
    desconto
DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Então, tentei com esse comando e os resultado foram todos os descontos com valores 0 (Zero).

Comment: Tentei também assim...                                                                                 select 
    cliente_id, 
    desconto, 
    pedidos_detalhes.pedido_id, 
    cliente_tipo 
from 
    pedidos_detalhes 
inner join 
    pedidos on pedidos_detalhes.pedido_id = pedidos.pedido_id 
ORDER BY
    desconto desc
LIMIT 10;

Comment: Esqueci de colocar DESC, que tras os dados do maior para o menor.
Também tem a opção ASC que trás os dados do menor para o maior.

Comment: e o resultado trouxe descontos 0.10 em todos os descontos, aumentei o LIMIT para 100 e todos os descontos são 0.10

Comment: Então com DESC traz todos os descontos igual a 0.10

Comment: Então, mas nesse caso ele está ordenando os resultados do maior para o menor, se remover a clausula LIMIT 100, ele trara todos os resultados ordenados pelo desconto, certo ?

Comment: Não, se eu tirar o LIMIT e deixar só o DESC, todos os campos descontos vem com valor 0.10

Comment: Ué, mas você tem todos esses descontos com 0.10 ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45682/discussion-between-duque-and-carlos-leandro-ferreira-de-alm).

Comment: Então... rsrsrrss. não...  se eu colocar o group by desconto ele traz os descontos na ordem decrescente de 0.10 a 0.00

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta, para você entender o significado das cláusulas.

---

Para você trazer os 10 clientes que obtiveram os maiores descontos por pedido, sem que o mesmo valor de desconto seja repetido. Deve utilizar a 
cláusula `GROUP BY`, que agrupa linhas baseado em semelhanças entre elas.

Para ordenar esses valores e pegar o maior por pedido você deve utilizar a cláusula `ORDER BY`. Pois quando precisamos que o resultado de nossa consulta a uma tabela seja fornecido em uma ordem específica, de acordo com um determinado critério, devemos usar a cláusula `ORDER BY` que, como o próprio nome diz, considera uma certa ordem para retornar os dados de uma consulta.